# Filter org mode weekly schedule by tag

Tags: org-mode

I have multiple scheduled tasks/events in different files properly labeled and I can't find a way to have the weekly schedule agenda view to filter by these labels. It just shows all the labels per day.

I've tried using the m option but It misses the weekdays and the properly structured view from the agenda weekly schedule.

Comment: Check out [Custom Agenda Views](https://orgmode.org/manual/Custom-Agenda-Views.html#Custom-Agenda-Views) in the manual.

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround to get what I want to do.

Since I have N `.org` files that have multiple scheduled events, I can go to a single file (say, the file to handle work tasks) press `C-c [` (`org-agenda-file-to-front`) which will show only this file as the weekly schedule.

Still, I'd like to just filter by the `WORK` tag in the global schedule and get the view to adjust itself.